# How to change GLPK input arguments for Integer programming in octave

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have solved linear programming problems using GLPK in octave where I have constructed C, A, b, lb, ub accordingly. My problem was minimization problem. So for `ctype` I used value `L` and for `vartype` the value was `C`.

```
[xmin, fmin] = (c,A,b,lb,ub,ctype, vartype,s)
```

Now I want to solve integer programming problem. If I just change the `vartype` to `I` and keep other arguments as they are then am I going to get the integral result? Any help will be really appreciated.